# Existence of a maximum for positive continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $u: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function vanishing at infinity. Then why does the maximum of $|u(x)|$ exist? I.e., a $x_0$ such that $|u(x_0)|=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u$ is not everywhere zero, and let $a$ be any positive value reached by $|u(x)|$. For $\|x\|$ large enough, say $\|x\|\geq R$, $|u(x)|<a$. We know $|u|$ attains a maximum $M\geq a$ on the compact set $\{x : \|x\|\leq R\}$, and because $|u|<a$ outside of it, it is a global maximum.